# TSQL OrderBy vs LINQ OrderBy Madness for UniqueIdentifier

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

After hours of trying to figure out why a piece of code is out of sync i came to the realization that TSQL OrderBy differs greatly from Linq OrderBy for strings.  So naturally I had to find a way to make sure a statement from tsql returns the same order as linq so I used a uniqueidentifier(guid) as my primary, however that seems to be wacked.

Here is the order using Linq (using the Guid(UniqueID) type for the property)

```
var listings = validListings.Select(x => x.TempListing)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.UniqueID)
                            .ToList();
```

It seems TSQL uses the binary value of the uniqueidentifier to compare while LINQ uses the string value even though the row is GUID

**LINQ RESULTS (Printed) (first few)**

```
00460400-a41d-465d-83c5-225f697e7bb5
015bef8d-5fa3-4c03-8d05-bfecf74b36b9
0202b433-4748-4660-97a1-94d119209aa6
03f34eb0-45cd-4586-b7d2-6e337b441c43
05e41d20-be24-4f4f-b098-574744dd84f0
0767e5d5-afba-49ab-a047-c9f509c80d3a
08f87ba1-8aa8-48a6-8f98-c3b4c6511b76
0b4157c4-7bdc-4e98-a00c-9259af754844
0bd194d0-fb66-4a69-9718-2128594ff9b0
0cda256a-7632-47de-b867-a2bc46382881
0d36f81a-ca37-446e-a325-87b46ef5b8d3
0d89fd26-4204-4d0a-b187-73a36536a848
0e345ca9-3d5d-43ed-aa75-fbd356f94535
0e767557-87ea-4c31-9f54-75d354a87d0f
0f62fc97-85b0-4611-b3e5-0c5ae4f12a18
1020d776-9810-4122-a9ef-3c527f21970c
```

**TSQL FIRST FEW**

```
9C5231CE-01DE-4A20-A4C9-001AD0D28512
3D52B47C-B29C-44A8-99F9-00AA660610A8
FDA7B67D-AEDB-4644-96E4-0147A0EEC29D
C8C7B677-76EB-41D3-B11C-020B9047EB00
487FF542-599B-42D4-BCE3-02C5D569E509
BDAA48DB-60AF-4A36-AFDB-02FA706EE87F
2CD9D59C-C2B5-433C-9FD1-0444F0384BB3
D44695A3-6FEF-4842-BFCB-048C110FA178
28FF051C-38A7-424F-B657-0698452DFE36
D9320EC6-64CD-4C26-8C5C-088C04E22AD7
D9F7FDC1-16D6-4C3A-B117-0908A234DF95
7DB09D09-F10B-4F33-9390-09211F9B2958
D970EE98-B575-4E73-BBAC-0981D6DC1682
9B05CDD9-2D85-486B-BC6B-0BA7E44F6021
539D22ED-FF2A-4376-A650-0BFE184C0E26
0F62FC97-85B0-4611-B3E5-0C5AE4F12A18
5D8EF134-0DC2-4B32-9F02-0C65940C1BCF
```

**How can I make them both return the same result?**

Comment: What's the question?  Why?  Because that's how each platform sorts them.  Guid is not a good choice for a sortable column.  Use a AutoIncrement integer instead.

Comment: how can i make them both return the same result (added to original post)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have discovered, C# (`System.Guid`) and SQL Server [use different algorithms to sort GUIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want SQL Server to sort GUIDs the way `System.Guid` does, then convert it to VARCHAR.

If you want to sort `Guid`s in C# the way SQL does, convert the `Guid` values to `System.Data.SqlGuid`:

```
var listings = validListings.Select(x =>x.TempListing)
                            .OrderBy(x=> new SqlGuid(x.UniqueID)).ToList();
```

That said, GUID is not an appropriate data type for a sortable column - I would switch to an `IDENTITY` column if possible.

Comment: In this particular case I am trying to obtain the identity column for the children (using SQLBulkCopy) so i save the parents... identity column is generated.. return them and add them to their children... your answer worked... trying to implement this solution http://www.sysexpand.com/?path=howto/bulk-insert

Comment: New URL is http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/bulk-insert Thanks for referring.